# round and update elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, typeerror

I have a list `lats` where each element looks like this:

```
48.16821784360847
48.1684475413586
48.16839850451211
```

I want to iterate through the whole list, and update the list such that each item is rounded to 3 decimal places. For example, the new list should be :

```
48.168
48.168
48.168
```

I am trying this :

```py
for i in lats:
    lats[i] = round(i, 3)
```

but it throws an error that :

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `for i in lats:` `i` will be the number (like `48.16821784360847`). If you use `for i in range(len(lats)):` instead `i` will be `0,1,2` and so on.

This will work:

```
for i in range(len(lats)):
    lats[i] = round(lats[i], 3)
print(lats)
```

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
for i,j in enumerate (lats):
    lats[i] = round(j, 3)
```

The error is the following.
The elements of the lists are floating point numbers. So when you iterate over it, `i` is equal to a value in that list. And list indexing can only be done with integers. `lats[i]` is substituting a floating point value which raises an error

Answer (score 2):

The error speaks for itself -

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

The problem is in your for loop -

```
for i in lats:
```

What this does is grab each element in lats per iteration, thus the problem is you're essentially trying to do -

```
lats[48.16821784360847] = round(i, 3)
```

Therefore, you need to do -

```
for i in range(len(lats)):
```

Answer (score 1):

In your solution i is a latitude and not its index. Thus the error

List comp

```py
lats[:] = [round(lat, 3) for lat in lats]
```

Map

```py
lats[:] = map(lambda x: round(x, 3), lats)
lats[:] = map(lambda x: x.__round__(3), lats)
```